# JavaScript: parsing JSONP callback response from GitHub API

Tags: javascript, jsonp, github-api

I'm creating an Express route that calls the GitHub API with a `?callback=foo` pattern added to the endpoint so that it will return the Link headers which I'll need to parse out the `Link:` header because it contains the link that I'll have to call to get the next page of the response.

The problem is that the response has the expected pattern, but when I try to create a function to tease out the `meta` and `data` portions of the function, they turn up undefined.

My code:

```
app.get('/populate', function(req, res, next) {
        console.log('/populate route hit');
        var token = "<something>";
        var options = {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users?callback=resp',
            headers: {
                'User-Agent': 'Our-App',
                'Authorization': 'token '+ token 
            }
        };
        api(options) // 'api' is request-promise module, makes http requests
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response); // Note 1
            function resp(res) {
                var meta = res.meta;
                var data = res.data;
                console.log('meta ', meta); // Note 2
                console.log('data ', data);
            }
            resp(response);
```

**Note 1**: The response looks like:

```
        /**/resp({"meta":{"X-RateLimit-Limit":"5000","X-RateLimit-Remaining":"4993",
    "X-RateLimit-Reset":"1435297775","X-OAuth-Scopes":"public_repo, user:email",
    "X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes":"repo","Cache-Control":"private, max-age=60, s-maxage=60",
    "Vary":"Accept, Authorization, Cookie, X-GitHub-OTP",
"ETag":"\"0cbbd180648a54f839a237b0302025db\"",
    "X-GitHub-Media-Type":"github.v3; format=json",
    "Link":[["https://api.github.com/users?callback=resp&since=46",
{"rel":"next"}],["https://api.github.com/users{?since}",
{"rel":"first"}]],"status":200},"data":[{"login":"mojombo","id":1,
        ...etc etc...
        }]})
```

The response looks like it's been JSON.stringified but when I `JSON.parse(response)` it returns an error. I don't know how to access the deeply-embedded `Link:` headers and even the `data`, which looks like JSON, too.

**Note 2** The res.meta and res.data log as *undefined*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response isn't JSON, it's [*JSONP*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP). JSONP is a cross-domain mechanism for retrieving data. You don't use XHR (e.g., `app.get`) to request JSONP, you use a `script` tag. (Because XHR is limited by the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy); `script` tags aren't.)

If your call retrieving that data via XHR works, it means cross-domain XHR calls are allowed in your situation (the server supports [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) with your page's origin, and the browser supports CORS). You can get JSON instead of JSONP by removing the `?callback=resp` in the URL.

Comment: Thank you. I used the `?callback=resp` because the resulting JSONP shows the `Link:` header in the `meta` property, while the JSON without the callback does not. Is there another way to access the response `Link` header? (Need it to know which paginated URI I need to pass to the API next...)

Comment: @zahabba: I don't know the github API, but a quick glance at the data suggests that the `since` parameter in that `Link` is just the `id` of the last user. `https://api.github.com/users` gives me 46 users, with `id` values 1 to 46. The equivalent JSONP gives me a `Link` with `since=46`. And if I do `https://api.github.com/users?since=46`, I get users 47-91. So...

Comment: They warn in their documentation not to compute the value of the `since` parameter and use the URL in the `Link` header. But your method seems to be more sensible and I can return to getting a JSON response without the callback. Thanks again!

Comment: @zahabba: The alternative, of course, is to use the JSONP feed. I don't know how you'd add those headers to the request, though, if they're necessary. Presumably Github's documentation would tell you. You "consume" JSONP by creating a global function, and using that function's name as the `?callback=xxxxx` value. You append a script tag with the URL, and when the script loads, it calls the function with the data (already parsed).